# VBA Word add an existing shape to a primary header

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to build a simple rectangle shape first and then add the built shape to the first section header (primary) in Word. But there does not seem to be an API for doing that. Instead, it seems that I must recreate a new shape inside of the header.

Normal code for creating a shape inside the header (the Add and Create operations are combined into one API 'AddShape'):

```
Set hf = doc.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)
Set shp = hf.shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 0, 0, 50, 50)
```

What I would rather do is something like this (pseudocode):

```
Set hf = doc.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)
Set shp = MyFunctionForBuildingAShapeThatIAlreadyUseElseWhere
hf.Shapes.Add(shp)
```

Is that kind of operation possible? I'm trying not to duplicate the code for building the shape since I use that code to build a shape for use outside of the header. Thank you.

Comment: A shape has to exist somewhere - it can't be "abstracted" away from the document.  If you refactor your shape-building code into a separate sub with a parameter which accepts a location then maybe you can use the same code for both locations.

Comment: Thank you. While I was away from my computer for a few hours, I figured out the same thing - shapes can only exist in some kind of shapes lists, despite being "objects." If @Tim's comment was an answer instead of a comment, I would mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's the same shape, simply point to the original's anchor and use the .FormattedText method to replicate it in the header. For example:

```
Dim doc As Document, Rng As Range
Set doc = ActiveDocument
With doc
  Set Rng = .Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
  Rng.Collapse wdCollapseStart
  Rng.FormattedText = .Shapes(1).Anchor.FormattedText
End With
```

Comment: Thank you for the extra clarity. Does FormattedText replicate the entire shape (with associated Textframe.Text) into the header? I've modified my code to first create the shapes inside or outside of the header as necessary and then call a common subroutine to do the formatting of all the shape and text properties. That way, only the shape creation code is "duplicated" (and not really duplicated, since it creates the shape in different Shapes collections...

Comment: If you mean an individual shape having text content, and/or a group, yes.